# How to add border to RoundedRectangle in flutter

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter-layout, border

I am trying to achieve [image]
but I am unable to

Here is my code:

```dart
Center(
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            ClipPath(
                clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
                    )
                ),
                child: Container(
                    height: 70.0,
                    width: 70.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.orange,
                                width: 7.0
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ],
    ),
)
```

Using this code, I am getting [image]

As shown in above image I am not able to add the black border.
Please help me guys, I am new to flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.grey, Colors.orange],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.86, 0.1]
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

The output:
[image]

#UPDATE

If you want the border in just the top, left and right.

Try this.

```
ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  right: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  top: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    width: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: what if i want only top, left right border not bottom

Comment: border not apply to corners of the reactangle

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
    body: Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            child: Container(
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                  bottom: BorderSide.none,
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 70.0,
                      height: 7.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

You may freely decide which side of the border you want and the colour and width. You can also stack and realign the orange linings by adding more `Align` widgets in the `Stack`.

[See the result of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCiR3.png)

Comment: border not applied to corners of recangle